# Proof regarding hyperbolas

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given the parameters $a,b>0$ we set $c:=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $e:=\large\frac{c}{a}$ (eccentricity),

the focal points are $F=(c,0)$ and $F'=(-c,0)$,

the directrix $L$ with the equation $x=\large\frac{a^2}{c}$

and the hyperbola $H=\{P\in\mathbb{R}^2:\large\frac{d(P,F)}{d(P,L)}\normalsize =e\}$.

How to prove this statement?

$P=(x,y)\in H\Rightarrow \large\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}\normalsize=1\Rightarrow|{d(P,F)-d(P,F')}|=2a\Rightarrow P=(x,y)\in H$

---

**I've come so far:**

Since we have $P=(x,y)\in H\iff \large\frac{d(P,F)}{d(P,L)}\normalsize =e$

The following must hold:

$\large\frac{\sqrt{(p_1-c)^2+(p_2-0)^2}}{d(P,L)}\normalsize =e\iff\large\frac{x^2}{a^2}\normalsize -\large\frac{y^2}{b^2}\normalsize =1$

$\iff \sqrt{(p_1-c)^2+(p_2-0)^2}-\sqrt{(p_1+c)^2+(p_2-0)^2}=2a$

---

But now I don't know how to rewrite $d(P,L)$ in terms of the euclidean metric, since $L$ is a line.

How do I go from here?

Comment: You should show your work so that people who answer the question know what to focus in on.

Comment: @Zach466920 Honestly, I don't know how to start.

Comment: @Arthur: Are you familiar with the formula for the distance between two points and the formula for the distance between a point and a line? If so, use them to re-write the condition $\frac{d(P,F)}{d(P,L)} = e$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ and $a$ and $c$. See where that gets you.

Comment: @Blue $d$ is the euclidean metric, but i don't know what to do with $d(P,L)$ since $L$ is a line...

Comment: @Arthur: If $P=(p,q)$ and $L: A x + B y + C = 0$, then $$d(P,L) = \frac{|Ap+Bq+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$

Comment: @Blue does it matter if I write $L: Ax+By+C=0$ or $y=mx+c$? I don't quite know what to do with the $A,B,C$.

Comment: @Arthur: Form is *definitely* important to the formula. :) But, if you have $y=mx+c$, then you can re-write it as $mx-y+c=0$, so that $A=m$, $B=-1$, $C=c$. (You could also re-write it as $-mx+y-c=0$, so that $A=-m$, $B=1$, $C=-c$, but the various squares and absolute values in the formula cause the two approaches to give the same result ... as they should.) In particular, the Standard Form equation for directrix $L$ is $1x + 0 y -\frac{ a^2}{c}=0$, so ...

Comment: @Blue Thanks. I'll try it.